# ocamlopt on Windows doesn't produce executable

Tags: winapi, executable, ocaml

Here's a simple OCaml program: helloworld.ml

```
print_string "Hello world...\n" ;;
```

I'm using OCaml 3.11.0 (MSVC built), VS 2008, and of course [FlexDLL](http://alain.frisch.fr/flexdll.html)

Here's how I compile it (ran from the VS 2008 shell):
ocamlopt helloworld.ml -o helloworld

No executable created. Is there something wrong?
The program compiled and ran on Linux, though.

Comment: it has to do with the linking phase. Check your installation of ocaml and the windows toolchain required.

Answer (score 1):

Show the full output from ocamlopt.

`-o helloworld` will produce binary helloworld (without extension).

If you want an .exe extension -- specify it explicitly

```
ocamlopt helloworld.ml -o helloworld.exe
```